# A lost command for vim registers

Tags: vim

I may be becoming demented in my old age but **I SWEAR** that, a week or so ago, while hunting around through Vim macros, I found a post somewhere that showed how to bring up a screen with the entire Register set (including those which were currently blank) displayed. This screen was both scrollable & editable. It was unlike the `:reg` or `:registers` command which shows the active registers only (not the inactive) and which operates like **more** - start at the top, move to the bottom & quit.

Well,I played with it for an afternoon, thought this is good, I'll remember this (and this is old age - the onset of nominal aphasia) but I forgot it.  I've checked all over, my Firefox history, my Vim [**:**] history & **:h registers** but I can't locate it.

Any help gratefully received

dmk

Comment: The behavior you describe looks a lot like `q:`, `q/` or `q?` but those are not for registers. My guess is that you are not looking for a built-in Vim command but for a custom one: the only built-in commands available for listing your registers are AFAIK `:reg[isters]` and, maybe but it does exactly the same as `:reg`, `:browse reg[isters]`.

Answer (score 3):

There's no such command, though something like this could surely be implemented (via a scratch buffer, and `:redir` of `:registers`, or a custom routine, and mappings to transfer the edits back to the register; might make a nice plugin).

Comment: And we all know what happens when you see a plugin opportunity ;-)